# Export image: Error: Internal error. (Error code: 13), I used my code many times and suddendly it stoped working

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, export, error, image

I want to export Sentinal 1 images to my drive. My shapefiles are in ESPG:4326, the images are in different systems, and I want to project the images to ESPG:3995 while exporting. The code was working very well in both JS and Python API, and I exported 1000 pics from different coordinates! But suddenly it stopped working with this non informative error 13 in both APIs!

I provided some code for test. do you have any idea what happend!! As I didn't change the code it might not be from my side!! did thay updated anything in their system since last week!!! It is so weird!
This is the link to the code in code.earthengine:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/396af2d8a50f9ec5f407c3b0b612951d

and this one in python:

```
rectangleCoordinates = ee.Geometry.Polygon([
            [
              16.602142120265494,
              76.75329817519014
            ],
            [
              16.781513666602333,
              76.88972383367935
            ],
            [
              17.243074550695404,
              76.85764127085562
            ],
            [
              17.059361308259593,
              76.7215564071655
            ],
            [
              16.602142120265494,
              76.75329817519014
            ]
          ])

out_dir = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Downloads')
filename = os.path.join(out_dir, 'landsat.tif')
image = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD/S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSH_20150120T061529_20150120T061554_004251_0052CA_9943');

img = image.reduceRegion(reducer= ee.Reducer.percentile([5, 95]),geometry = rectangleCoordinates)
perc_ = ee.Number(img)  

visParams = {
'bands' : image.bandNames().getInfo()[0],
'min': perc_.getInfo()[ image.bandNames().getInfo()[0]+'_p5'],
'max':  perc_.getInfo()[image.bandNames().getInfo()[0]+'_p95'],
'gamma': 1}

centroid = rectangleCoordinates.centroid()
lng, lat = centroid.getInfo()['coordinates']
print("lng = {}, lat = {}".format(lng, lat))
print('Sentinal Image CRS: ', image.getInfo()['bands'][0]['crs']) # shape file crs is: 'epsg:4326'

image_vis = image.visualize(**visParams)
geemap.ee_export_image_to_drive(
    image_vis, description='landsat1',crs='EPSG:3995', folder='export',
     region=rectangleCoordinates,scale=10, maxPixels= 4196910
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If anybody else has the same problem, it is not your code; the source of the issue is their system.

As they answer a report in IssueTracker.google.com:
"This error is due to an upgrade of our projection handling tools. Exports in some projections (like polar stereographic)
are currently failing due to the upgrade. We're working on the issue."